# MySQL Update multiple rows on a single column based on values from that same column

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
ID     Key     Value     Order
1      gender  m         0
2      gender  f         0

34     age     10        0
35     age     80        0
```

To update these rows I have to use the following:

```
UPDATE `DemoGroup` SET `value` = 'male' WHERE `value` = 'm'
UPDATE `DemoGroup` SET `value` = 'female' WHERE `value` = 'f'
UPDATE `DemoGroup` SET `value` = '10-19' WHERE `value` = '10'
UPDATE `DemoGroup` SET `value` = '80-89' WHERE `value` = '80'
```

Is there a way to consolidate this into one update statement, without using the ID (which is not guaranteed to be the same), such as (even though this won't work)...

```
UPDATE `DemoGroup` 
SET `value`= CASE `value`
    WHEN 'm' THEN 'male',
    WHEN 'f' THEN 'female' END 
WHERE `value` = 'm' OR `value` = 'f'
```

Even more of a bonus (but not nessesary) is if I could figure out how to set the Order field as well for each row...

Comment: What is the purpose of order?

Comment: What happens if you remove the "value" after CASE? Your query looks good other than that.

Comment: @gview - order is set/used when displaying values based off of the key to the end user & we want to have greater control over which appears first, second, third, etc to the end user.

Comment: When you compare yours to mine, you will notice you added commas that are not part of the syntax between the cases.

Comment: @Tim: I thought that might be the purpose.  I don't think that there's a way something generic could surmise the arbitrary order you would assign, although afaik the results in mysql come out in key order unless there's an ORDER BY modifying that behavior.  When the row is entered, if it does not match key order.  You Could actually pull off setting it in one query, using SET ORDER = IF(...) and build a ternary for any specific cases you have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should probably update the values based not only on the value of `value` but on the value of `key`, otherwise you could update 'm' to 'male' when key is 'shirt-size'.

```
UPDATE `DemoGroup` 
SET `value` = CASE 
    WHEN (`key`, `value`) = ('gender', 'm') THEN 'male'
    WHEN (`key`, `value`) = ('gender', 'f') THEN 'female'
    WHEN (`key`, `value`) = ('age', '10')   THEN '10-19'
    WHEN (`key`, `value`) = ('age', '80')   THEN '80-89'
    ELSE `value` -- no-op for other values
  END 
WHERE `key` IN ('gender','age');
```

Comment: I love this solution, but i get a syntax error when trying to execute, can you see anything in it that would cause this?

Comment: My apologies, there should be no commas between the cases.  I've edited the above to fix it, and I've tested the query on MySQL 5.1.57.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does have a case function.  Try:

```
UPDATE DemoGroup SET `value` = 
CASE `value` WHEN 'm' THEN 'male'
WHEN 'f' THEN 'female'
WHEN '10' THEN '10-19'
WHEN '80' THEN '80-89' END;
```

Comment: This worked quite well, but cleared out the values I didn't want to change - which part of that might be my fault for not specifying