# How to update newly added column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

[image]

Hi

I have added a new column "Hours" and I want to update that column. I wrote the following code but didn't work. What is the problem of the following code?

```
UPDATE OFFICER
SET HOURS=5 AND HOURS=4 AND HOURS=4 AND HOURS=3
WHERE NAME IN('KASUN','MANEL','LALA');
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Don't try to set the same column several times like that.

Comment: Can you describe your update logic better?

Comment: Not sure about your query. Please use if condition.

Comment: Maybe duplicate?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7261918/3727050

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I simply want to add some numbers to the hour column

Comment: Or this duplicate ? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62051/alter-table-rename-a-column

Comment: Add some sample table data, before and after the update. As formatted text, not images!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to populate your new column with exactly those values, you could use an `UPDATE` with a `CASE WHEN` like:

```
UPDATE OFFICER
   SET HOURS = CASE WHEN NAME = 'KASUN' THEN 5
                    WHEN NAME = 'MANEL' THEN 4
                    WHEN NAME = 'LALA'  THEN 3
               END
 WHERE NAME IN('KASUN','MANEL','LALA');
 ;
```

In case you want to **populate rows with random numbers**, you could just generate a random number like:

```
UPDATE OFFICER
   SET HOURS = ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 6) + 1
 WHERE NAME IN('KASUN','MANEL','LALA');
 ;
```

The `ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 6) + 1` will generate a random number between 1 and 6

Answer (score 1):

Guess what, I think you may need `CASE WHEN`:

```
UPDATE OFFICER
SET HOURS = CASE WHEN NAME = 'KASUN' THEN 5
                 WHEN NAME = 'MANEL' THEN 4
                 WHEN NAME = 'LALA' THEN 3
                 ELSE HOURS
            END;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there will be condition means you can able to set multiple value for same field based on condition like ..

```
UPDATE OFFICER SET HOURS = CASE WHEN NAME= 'KASUN' THEN 5 
                   WHEN NAME= 'MANEL' THEN 4 
                   WHEN NAME= 'LALA' THEN 3  END WHERE NAME IN('KASUN','MANEL','LALA');
```

Other wise you can make separate entry like below-

```
    UPDATE OFFICER  SET HOURS=5 WHERE NAME='KASUN';

    UPDATE OFFICER SET HOURS=4 WHERE NAME ='MANEL';

    UPDATE OFFICER AND HOURS=3 WHERE NAME='LALA';
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant set more than one value for one column at the same time you can just set one value like this

```
UPDATE OFFICER  SET HOURS = 5 
WHERE NAME IN('KASUN','MANEL','LALA');
```

Comment: THANKS E-housma Mardini ! It worked when I add 1 column at a time. Thanks. Do you know how we can add all the columns at once?

Comment: my friend you cant set more than one value to the same filed in one row